# Getting the value of multiple UISlider's in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uislider

I have a UITableView with UISliders on each row. They all call the -(void) sliderValueChanged: (id)sender method.

I then have a label outside the UITableView that I populate with the value of the UISlider minus the CoreData value of Incomes. The problem is how do I take away the total slider values from the total income value. This is what I have so far but the slider value which I store in the NSNumber previousNumber variable does not work properly. Any help would great.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UISlider *theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55,20,220,45)] autorelease];
        theSlider.maximumValue=[self.totalIncomes floatValue];
        theSlider.minimumValue=0;       
        [theSlider addTarget:self action: @selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell addSubview:theSlider];
    }

    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];

            Categories  *category = (Categories *)[categoriesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[category name]];
            [category release];


    return cell;
}


-(void) sliderValueChanged: (id)sender
{
    UISlider *control = (UISlider *) sender;
    float value = control.value;
    float total = [self.totalIncomes floatValue];

    if ([self.previousNumber floatValue] < value) {
        total = total - (value - [self.previousNumber floatValue]);
    }
    else {
        total = total + ([self.previousNumber floatValue] - value);
    }

    self.totalIncomes = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (float)total];
    NSLog(@"%.2f", [self.totalIncomes floatValue]);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[self.totalIncomes floatValue]];
    self.previousNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)value];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make complete sense to me. You have one UISlider per row in your table, but you only have one self.previousNumber. Which UISlider is it associated with? And where does it's initial value come from? We need to see more code... At a minimum, to make something like this work, you'll need a one-to-one mapping between your UISlider objects and the previousNumber objects.

Comment: At the moment the self.previousnumber gets the values from all the uisliders. This is the problem. I have started to work on using NSMutableDictionary to store the previous numbers with the UISlider's tag atribute as the key. For example to collect: float previous = [[self.previousNumbers objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", control.tag]] floatValue]; and to assign: float previous = [[self.previousNumbers objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", control.tag]] floatValue];